# Rails nested fields_for with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Rails: 3.2.18

I am attempting to build a nested form which accepts attributes for a has_many relationship. In this case the form is for a `Listing` which is accepting attributes for a `Shipment` which is also accepting attributes for, and has many `ShipmentPackages`. Here's a look at the code:

```
# listing.rb
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipment
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipment
end

# shipment.rb
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipment_packages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipment_packages
end

# Here's the form itself:
= form_for(@listing) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :shipment do |shipment_form|
    - @listing.shipment.shipment_packages.each do |shipment_package|
      = shipment_form.fields_for 'shipment_packages_attributes[]', shipment_package do |shipment_package_form|
        = shipment_package_form.text_field(:length)

# listings_controller.rb
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @listing.update_attributes(params[:listing])
  end
end
```

When the form is submitted, the parameters are getting passed in the way I would expect them to be:

```
Parameters: {"listing"=>{"shipment_attributes"=>{"shipment_packages_attributes"=>{"3"=>{"length"=>"11"}, "4"=>{"length"=>"6"}}}
```

In this case, the `id`s of my two existing `ShipmentPackages` are `3` and `4`; therefore this ^ is what I would expect to see. However, rather than updating the attributes of the existing `ShipmentPackages` (3 and 4), this ignores them and is creating brand new `ShipmentPackage` records. My `Shipment` now owns 4 `ShipmentPackages` (3, 4, 5, 6).

Let me know if there are any further details that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the form to include the `id` in the `shipment_packages_attributes` hash:

```
{"listing"=>{"shipment_attributes"=>{"shipment_packages_attributes"=>{"3"=>{"id" => "3", "length"=>"11"}, "4"=>{"id" => "4", "length"=>"6"}}}
```

Comment: You have saved my life, I am eternally grateful! Ended up adding a `hidden_field` containing the ID to each object. This did the trick. No idea why it's necessary, but thanks!

Comment: This is the greatest answer that has ever or will ever exist! :-O